# Width of Fieldset Changes with Data Input

Tags: html, css

The width of my field set is changing every time I input data to my table.

This is my CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">
 .frmField_set {
   align: right;
   color: black;
   width: 89%;
   padding: 4px;
   text-align: left;
   font-family: sans-serif;
   font-style: normal;
   font-size: small;
   font-weight: bold;
   margin-left:auto;
   margin-right:auto;
 }
</style>
```

This is my HTML:

```
 <html>      
  <head>
   </head>
    <body>
    <fieldset class="frmField_set">
        <legend>Account Sale Item Table</legend>
        <div id="accountSaleItem"></div>
          <table>
            <tr>
              <td>
            <span style="margin-left:5px;
            font-family:sans-serif; font-size:12;">Total</span></td>
              <td>
            <span id="qty" style="margin-left: 400px;
            font-family:sans-serif; font-size: 12;">0.00</span></td>
              <td>
            <span id="accountSaleAmount" style="margin-left: 365px;
            font-family:sans-serif; font-size: 12;">0.00</span></td>
            </tr>       
        </table>                
    </fieldset>
   </body>
 </html>
```

Does anyone know why this is happening and how I can stop the fieldset's width from increasing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this CSS:

```
td {
  max-width: 391px;
}
```

I made a JSFiddle it's working there: http://jsfiddle.net/zjn917up/

Comment: Thank you sir.. I will add it to my css. I hope this will work for me. I will inform you if it work.. :D

Comment: It did not work sir, I think the problem to my code is the span. When I add the margin-left in my span my fieldset's width is now unstable.

Comment: You accepted the answer - did you get it working or do you need help still?

Comment: Actually it did not work for me sir but thanks for your help though. I come up with another solution and i found out what is the real problem. I get it now. Thank you again sir..GodBless